# How to zoom out/ scale down in Linear transformation scene in manim?

Tags: python, manim

My vectors are going off the screen in Linear transformation scene in `manimce`.

[image]

How to move the camera back?
Or alternatively scale down the number plane such that 7 is visible in the y axis?

I dont want the zoom out effect/animation, just the zoomed out camera from the start.

**What I have tried(for moving the camera):**

**1.[Set camera frame](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/master/English/extra/faqs/faqs.md#change-position-and-size-of-the-camera)**

`self.camera_frame.set_width(20)`
Didn't work because this only works in `MovingCameraScene`. Mine is a `LinearTransformationScene`.

**What I have tried(for scaling down):**

**1.Axes()**

```
ax = Axes().add_coordinates()

self.add(ax)
```

Both the axes will be shown making a mess.[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5FiV.png)

**2."x_max": 10**

```
class LinearTransformationSceneExample(LinearTransformationScene):
    CONFIG = {
        "show_basis_vectors": True,
        "foreground_plane_kwargs": {
            "x_max": 10,
            "x_min": -10,
            "y_max": 10,
            "y_min": -10,
            "faded_line_ratio": 0
        },

    }
```

Didn't show any effect at all. Maybe because this code is for manim3b1b version and I am using manimce?

3.[**axis_config**](https://www.reddit.com/r/manim/comments/nrli6h/how_to_config_axis_labels_with_axes/)

According to manim documentation,

**[axis_config](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.coordinate_systems.Axes.html)** (Optional[dict]) –
`Arguments to be passed to NumberLine that influences both axes.`

```
graph = Axes(
            x_range=np.array([-8, 8, 2]),
            y_range=np.array([-4, 4, 2]),
            x_length=13,
            y_length=7,
            axis_config={
                'color' : WHITE,
                'stroke_width' : 4,
                'include_numbers' : False,
                'decimal_number_config' : {
                    'num_decimal_places' : 0,
                    'include_sign' : True,
                    'color' : WHITE
                }
            },

        )
```

Didnt work either. No effect at all...

But this seems to work in [this case in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/manim/comments/nrli6h/how_to_config_axis_labels_with_axes/) but there the OP uses `class scene(m.Scene):`

---

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can inherit the MovingCameraScene along with the LinearTransformationScene. Then you call the init. I did that and it works for me.

```
class Test(LinearTransformationScene, MovingCameraScene):
    def __init__(self):
        LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
        )
```

Something like this.

Then in construct method,

```
def construct(self):
    self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.set(width=20))
    #something else
```

Then you set  Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't tried it. Will reply after trying. Thanks for the answer.